# I am trying to build php for openlitespeed but getting error

Tags: ssh, debian, vps, debian-stretch

I am trying to build php7.4 for my openlitespeed but unable to build form webconsole and from ssh also

when i run from ssh

```
./configure --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/webp/ --with-litespeed
```

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-webp-dir,
>   --with-litespeed checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E checking for a sed that
>   does not truncate output... /bin/sed checking build system type...
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>   checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu checking for
>   pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config checking pkg-config is at least
>   version 0.9.0... yes checking for cc... cc checking whether the C
>   compiler works... yes checking for C compiler default output file
>   name... a.out checking for suffix of executables... checking whether
>   we are cross compiling... no checking for suffix of object files... o
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes checking
>   whether cc accepts -g... yes checking for cc option to accept ISO
>   C89... none needed checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
>   checking for icc... no checking for suncc... no checking how to run
>   the C preprocessor... cc -E checking for ANSI C header files... yes
>   checking for sys/types.h... yes checking for sys/stat.h... yes
>   checking for stdlib.h... yes checking for string.h... yes checking for
>   memory.h... yes checking for strings.h... yes checking for
>   inttypes.h... yes checking for stdint.h... yes checking for
>   unistd.h... yes checking minix/config.h usability... no checking
>   minix/config.h presence... no checking for minix/config.h... no
>   checking whether it is safe to define **EXTENSIONS**... yes checking
>   whether ln -s works... yes checking for system library directory...
>   lib checking whether to enable runpaths... yes checking if compiler
>   supports -R... no checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
>   checking for gawk... gawk checking for bison... no checking for
>   re2c... no checking whether to enable computed goto gcc extension with
>   re2c... no checking whether C compiler accepts -fvisibility=hidden...
>   yes checking whether to force non-PIC code in shared modules... no
>   checking whether /dev/urandom exists... yes checking for global
>   register variables support... yes checking whether atof() accepts
>   NAN... no checking whether atof() accepts INF... no checking whether
>   HUGE_VAL == INF... yes checking whether HUGE_VAL + -HUGEVAL == NAN...
>   no checking whether __cpuid_count is available... yes checking for
>   pthreads_cflags... -pthread checking for pthreads_lib... pthread
>
> Configuring SAPI modules checking for Apache 2 handler module support
>   via DSO through APXS... no checking for setproctitle... no checking
>   sys/pstat.h usability... no checking sys/pstat.h presence... no
>   checking for sys/pstat.h... no checking for PS_STRINGS... no checking
>   for CLI build... yes checking for embedded SAPI library support... no
>   checking for FPM build... no checking for LiteSpeed support... no
>   checking for phpdbg support... yes checking for phpdbg web SAPI
>   support... no checking for phpdbg debug build... no checking for
>   phpdbg readline support... no checking whether termios.h defines
>   TIOCGWINSZ... no checking whether sys/ioctl.h defines TIOCGWINSZ...
>   yes checking for phpdbg and readline integration... disabled checking
>   for CGI build... yes checking for sun_len in sys/un.h... no checking
>   whether cross-process locking is required by accept()... no checking
>   for chosen SAPI module... none checking for executable SAPI
>   binaries...  cli phpdbg cgi
>
> Running system checks checking for sendmail... /usr/sbin/sendmail
>   checking whether system uses EBCDIC... no checking whether byte
>   ordering is bigendian... no checking whether writing to stdout
>   works... This is the test message -- yes checking for socket... yes
>   checking for socketpair... yes checking for htonl... yes checking for
>   gethostname... yes checking for gethostbyaddr... yes checking for
>   dlopen... no checking for **dlopen... no checking for dlopen in
>   -ldl... yes checking for dlsym... yes checking for sin in -lm... yes checking for inet_aton... yes checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
>   checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes checking for dirent.h... yes
>   checking for sys/param.h... yes checking for sys/types.h... (cached)
>   yes checking for sys/time.h... yes checking for netinet/in.h... yes
>   checking for alloca.h... yes checking for arpa/inet.h... yes checking
>   for arpa/nameser.h... yes checking for crypt.h... yes checking for
>   dns.h... no checking for fcntl.h... yes checking for grp.h... yes
>   checking for ieeefp.h... no checking for langinfo.h... yes checking
>   for locale.h... yes checking for malloc.h... yes checking for
>   monetary.h... yes checking for netdb.h... yes checking for poll.h...
>   yes checking for pwd.h... yes checking for resolv.h... yes checking
>   for strings.h... (cached) yes checking for syslog.h... yes checking
>   for sysexits.h... yes checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes checking for
>   sys/file.h... yes checking for sys/mman.h... yes checking for
>   sys/mount.h... yes checking for sys/poll.h... yes checking for
>   sys/resource.h... yes checking for sys/select.h... yes checking for
>   sys/socket.h... yes checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes checking
>   for sys/statfs.h... yes checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes checking for
>   sys/vfs.h... yes checking for sys/sysexits.h... no checking for
>   sys/uio.h... yes checking for sys/wait.h... yes checking for
>   sys/loadavg.h... no checking for termios.h... yes checking for
>   unistd.h... (cached) yes checking for unix.h... no checking for
>   utime.h... yes checking for sys/utsname.h... yes checking for
>   sys/ipc.h... yes checking for dlfcn.h... yes checking for
>   tmmintrin.h... yes checking for nmmintrin.h... yes checking for
>   immintrin.h... yes checking for fopencookie... yes checking for broken
>   getcwd... no checking for broken gcc optimize-strlen... no checking
>   whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h checking for
>   struct tm.tm_zone... yes checking for missing declarations of
>   reentrant functions... done checking for fclose declaration... ok
>   checking for struct flock... yes checking for socklen_t... yes
>   checking size of intmax_t... 8 checking size of ssize_t... 8 checking
>   size of ptrdiff_t... 8 checking size of short... 2 checking size of
>   int... 4 checking size of long... 8 checking size of long long... 8
>   checking size of size_t... 8 checking for int8... no checking for
>   int16... no checking for int32... no checking for int64... no checking
>   for int8_t... yes checking for int16_t... yes checking for int32_t...
>   yes checking for int64_t... yes checking for uint8... no checking for
>   uint16... no checking for uint32... no checking for uint64... no
>   checking for uint8_t... yes checking for uint16_t... yes checking for
>   uint32_t... yes checking for uint64_t... yes checking for u_int8_t...
>   yes checking for u_int16_t... yes checking for u_int32_t... yes
>   checking for u_int64_t... yes checking for __builtin_expect... yes
>   checking for __builtin_clz... yes checking for __builtin_ctzl... yes
>   checking for __builtin_ctzll... yes checking for
>   __builtin_smull_overflow... yes checking for __builtin_smulll_overflow... yes checking for __builtin_saddl_overflow... yes checking for __builtin_saddll_overflow... yes checking for __builtin_ssubl_overflow... yes checking for __builtin_ssubll_overflow... yes checking for __builtin_cpu_init... yes checking for __builtin_cpu_supports... yes checking for ssse3
>   instructions supports... yes checking for sse4.2 instructions
>   supports... yes checking for avx instructions supports... yes checking
>   for avx2 instructions supports... yes checking for struct
>   tm.tm_gmtoff... yes checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
>   checking for struct stat.st_rdev... yes checking for struct
>   stat.st_blocks... yes checking for size_t... yes checking for uid_t in
>   sys/types.h... yes checking for struct sockaddr_storage... yes
>   checking for field sa_len in struct sockaddr... no checking for
>   __attribute**((ifunc))... yes checking for **attribute**((target))... yes checking for IPv6 support... yes checking for alphasort... yes
>   checking for asctime_r... yes checking for chroot... yes checking for
>   ctime_r... yes checking for crypt... no checking for
>   explicit_memset... no checking for flock... yes checking for
>   fpclass... no checking for ftok... yes checking for funopen... no
>   checking for gai_strerror... yes checking for getcwd... yes checking
>   for getloadavg... yes checking for getlogin... yes checking for
>   getprotobyname... yes checking for getprotobynumber... yes checking
>   for getservbyname... yes checking for getservbyport... yes checking
>   for getrusage... yes checking for gettimeofday... yes checking for
>   gmtime_r... yes checking for getpwnam_r... yes checking for
>   getgrnam_r... yes checking for getpwuid_r... yes checking for getwd...
>   yes checking for glob... yes checking for grantpt... yes checking for
>   inet_ntoa... yes checking for inet_ntop... yes checking for
>   inet_pton... yes checking for localtime_r... yes checking for
>   lchown... yes checking for mbrlen... yes checking for memmove... yes
>   checking for mkstemp... yes checking for mmap... yes checking for
>   nice... yes checking for nl_langinfo... yes checking for poll... yes
>   checking for ptsname... yes checking for putenv... yes checking for
>   realpath... yes checking for rand_r... yes checking for scandir... yes
>   checking for setitimer... yes checking for setenv... yes checking for
>   shutdown... yes checking for sigprocmask... yes checking for statfs...
>   yes checking for statvfs... yes checking for std_syslog... no checking
>   for strcasecmp... yes checking for strfmon... yes checking for
>   strnlen... yes checking for strptime... yes checking for strtok_r...
>   yes checking for symlink... yes checking for tzset... yes checking for
>   unlockpt... yes checking for unsetenv... yes checking for usleep...
>   yes checking for utime... yes checking for vasprintf... yes checking
>   for asprintf... yes checking for nanosleep... yes checking for
>   memmem... yes checking how many arguments gethostbyname_r() takes...
>   six checking for nanosleep in -lrt... yes checking for getaddrinfo...
>   yes checking for __sync_fetch_and_add... yes checking for strlcat...
>   no checking for strlcpy... no checking for explicit_bzero... no
>   checking for getopt... yes checking for working alloca.h... yes
>   checking for alloca... yes checking for type of reentrant time-related
>   functions... POSIX checking for in_addr_t... yes checking for
>   crypt_r... no checking for asm goto... yes checking whether compiler
>   supports VLA... yes checking whether to enable valgrind support... yes
>   checking for valgrind... no
>
> General settings checking whether to include gcov symbols... no
>   checking whether to include debugging symbols... no checking whether
>   to dlopen extensions with RTLD_NOW instead of RTLD_LAZY... no checking
>   layout of installed files... PHP checking path to configuration
>   file... DEFAULT checking where to scan for configuration files...
>   checking whether to enable PHP's own SIGCHLD handler... no checking
>   whether to explicitly link against libgcc... no checking whether to
>   enable short tags by default... yes checking whether to enable
>   dmalloc... no checking whether to enable IPv6 support... yes checking
>   whether to enable DTrace support... no checking how big to make fd
>   sets... using system default
>
> Configuring extensions checking io.h usability... no checking io.h
>   presence... no checking for io.h... no checking for strtoll... yes
>   checking for atoll... yes checking whether to build with LIBXML
>   support... yes checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.6... yes checking for
>   OpenSSL support... no checking for Kerberos support... no checking
>   whether to use system default cipher list instead of hardcoded
>   value... no checking for PCRE library to use... bundled checking
>   whether to enable PCRE JIT functionality... yes checking whether to
>   enable the SQLite3 extension... yes checking for sqlite3 > 3.7.4...
>   yes checking for sqlite3_stmt_readonly in -lsqlite3... yes checking
>   for sqlite3_errstr in -lsqlite3... yes checking for
>   sqlite3_load_extension in -lsqlite3... yes checking for ZLIB
>   support... no checking whether to enable bc style precision math
>   functions... no checking for BZip2 support... no checking whether to
>   enable calendar conversion support... no checking whether to enable
>   ctype functions... yes checking for cURL support... no checking for
>   QDBM support... no checking for GDBM support... no checking for NDBM
>   support... no checking for TCADB support... no checking for LMDB
>   support... no checking for Berkeley DB4 support... no checking for
>   Berkeley DB3 support... no checking for Berkeley DB2 support... no
>   checking for DB1 support... no checking for DBM support... no checking
>   for CDB support... no checking for INI File support... no checking for
>   FlatFile support... no checking whether to enable DBA interface... no
>   checking whether to enable DOM support... yes checking for libxml-2.0
>
> > = 2.7.6... yes checking whether to build with Enchant support... no checking whether to enable EXIF (metadata from images) support... no
> >     checking for FFI support... no checking for fileinfo support... yes
> >     checking for strcasestr... yes checking for utimes... yes checking for
> >     strndup... yes checking whether to enable input filter support... yes
> >     checking whether to enable FTP support... no checking OpenSSL dir for
> >     FTP... no checking for GD support... no checking for external libgd...
> >     no checking for libwebp... no checking for libjpeg... no checking for
> >     libXpm... no checking for FreeType 2... no checking whether to enable
> >     JIS-mapped Japanese font support in GD... no checking for GNU gettext
> >     support... no checking for GNU MP support... no checking for mhash
> >     support... no checking size of long... (cached) 8 checking if we're at
> >     64-bit platform... yes checking for iconv support... yes checking for
> >     iconv... yes checking if iconv is glibc's... yes checking if iconv
> >     supports errno... yes checking if iconv supports //IGNORE... no
> >     checking if your cpp allows macro usage in include lines... yes
> >     checking for IMAP support... no checking for IMAP Kerberos support...
> >     no checking for IMAP SSL support... no checking whether to enable
> >     internationalization support... no checking whether to enable
> >     JavaScript Object Serialization support... yes checking for LDAP
> >     support... no checking whether to build with LDAP Cyrus SASL
> >     support... no checking whether to enable multibyte string support...
> >     no checking whether to enable multibyte regex support (requires
> >     oniguruma)... yes checking for MySQLi support... no checking for
> >     specified location of the MySQL UNIX socket... no checking for Oracle
> >     Database OCI8 support... no checking for Adabas support... no checking
> >     for SAP DB support... no checking for Solid support... no checking for
> >     IBM DB2 support... no checking for Empress support... no checking for
> >     Empress local access support... no checking for a custom ODBC
> >     support... no checking whether to build with iODBC support... no
> >     checking for Easysoft ODBC-ODBC Bridge support... no checking whether
> >     to build with unixODBC support... no checking for DBMaker support...
> >     no checking for any ODBC driver support... no checking whether to
> >     enable Zend OPcache support... yes checking whether to enable copying
> >     PHP CODE pages into HUGE PAGES... yes checking for mprotect... yes
> >     checking for sysvipc shared memory support... yes checking for mmap()
> >     using MAP_ANON shared memory support... yes checking for shm_open in
> >     -lrt... yes checking for mmap() using shm_open() shared memory support... yes checking for shm_unlink in -lrt... yes checking whether
> >     to enable pcntl support... no checking whether to enable PDO
> >     support... yes checking for PDO_DBLIB support via FreeTDS... no
> >     checking for Firebird support for PDO... no checking for MySQL support
> >     for PDO... no checking for the location of libz... no checking Oracle
> >     OCI support for PDO... no checking for ODBC v3 support for PDO... no
> >     checking for PostgreSQL support for PDO... no checking for sqlite 3
> >     support for PDO... yes checking for PDO includes...
> >     /usr/local/lsws/phpbuild/php-7.4.1/ext checking for sqlite3 > 3.7.4...
> >     yes checking for sqlite3_open_v2 in -lsqlite3... yes checking for
> >     sqlite3_close_v2 in -lsqlite3... yes checking for
> >     sqlite3_column_table_name in -lsqlite3... yes checking for PostgreSQL
> >     support... no checking for phar archive support... yes checking for
> >     phar openssl support... no checking whether to enable POSIX-like
> >     functions... yes checking sys/mkdev.h usability... no checking
> >     sys/mkdev.h presence... no checking for sys/mkdev.h... no checking
> >     sys/sysmacros.h usability... yes checking sys/sysmacros.h presence...
> >     yes checking for sys/sysmacros.h... yes checking for seteuid... yes
> >     checking for setegid... yes checking for setsid... yes checking for
> >     getsid... yes checking for getpgid... yes checking for ctermid... yes
> >     checking for mkfifo... yes checking for mknod... yes checking for
> >     setrlimit... yes checking for getrlimit... yes checking for
> >     getgroups... yes checking for makedev... no checking for initgroups...
> >     yes checking for getgrgid_r... yes checking for working ttyname_r()
> >     implementation... yes checking for utsname.domainname... yes checking
> >     for PSPELL support... no checking for libedit readline replacement...
> >     no checking for readline support... no checking whether to enable PHP
> >     sessions... yes checking for mm support... no checking whether pwrite
> >     works... yes checking whether pread works... yes checking whether to
> >     enable shmop support... no checking whether to enable SimpleXML
> >     support... yes checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.6... yes checking for
> >     SNMP support... no checking OpenSSL dir for SNMP... no checking
> >     whether to enable SOAP support... no checking whether to enable
> >     sockets support... no checking for sodium support... no checking
> >     whether flush should be called explicitly after a buffered io... no
> >     checking for crypt in -lcrypt... yes checking for standard DES
> >     crypt... yes checking for extended DES crypt... no checking for MD5
> >     crypt... yes checking for Blowfish crypt... no checking for SHA512
> >     crypt... yes checking for SHA256 crypt... yes checking whether the
> >     compiler supports **alignof**... yes checking whether the compiler
> >     supports aligned attribute... yes checking for asinh... yes checking
> >     for acosh... yes checking for atanh... yes checking for log1p... yes
> >     checking for hypot... yes checking for working POSIX fnmatch... yes
> >     checking for fork... yes checking if your OS can spawn processes with
> >     inherited handles... yes checking for res_nsearch... no checking for
> >     __res_nsearch... no checking for res_nsearch in -lresolv... no checking for __res_nsearch in -lresolv... yes checking for
> >     res_ndestroy... no checking for __res_ndestroy... no checking for
> >     res_ndestroy in -lresolv... no checking for __res_ndestroy in
> >     -lresolv... no checking for res_ndestroy in -lbind... no checking for __res_ndestroy in -lbind... no checking for res_ndestroy in -lsocket... no checking for __res_ndestroy in -lsocket... no checking for dns_search... no checking for __dns_search... no checking for
> >     dns_search in -lresolv... no checking for __dns_search in -lresolv...
> >     no checking for dns_search in -lbind... no checking for __dns_search
> >     in -lbind... no checking for dns_search in -lsocket... no checking for
> >     __dns_search in -lsocket... no checking for dn_expand... no checking for __dn_expand... yes checking for dn_skipname... no checking for
> >     __dn_skipname... yes checking for res_search... no checking for __res_search... yes checking whether strptime() declaration fails... yes checking wchar.h usability... yes checking wchar.h presence... yes
> >     checking for wchar.h... yes checking for mblen... yes checking for
> >     mbstate_t... yes checking atomic.h usability... no checking atomic.h
> >     presence... no checking for atomic.h... no checking whether
> >     arc4random_buf is declared... no checking for Argon2 support... no
> >     checking for net/if.h... yes checking for usable getifaddrs... yes
> >     checking whether to enable System V IPC support... no checking whether
> >     to enable System V semaphore support... no checking whether to enable
> >     System V shared memory support... no checking for TIDY support... no
> >     checking whether to enable tokenizer support... yes checking whether
> >     to enable XML support... yes checking whether to build with expat
> >     support... no checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.6... yes checking whether
> >     to enable XMLReader support... yes checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.6...
> >     yes checking whether to build with XMLRPC-EPI support... no checking
> >     whether to build with expat support... no checking iconv dir for
> >     XMLRPC-EPI... no checking whether to enable XMLWriter support... yes
> >     checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.6... yes checking whether to build with
> >     XSL support... no checking whether to enable zend-test extension... no
> >     checking for zip archive read/write support... no checking whether to
> >     enable mysqlnd... no checking whether to disable compressed protocol
> >     support in mysqlnd... yes
>
> Configuring PEAR checking whether to install PEAR... no
>
> Configuring Zend checking cpuid.h usability... yes checking cpuid.h
>   presence... yes checking for cpuid.h... yes checking for getpid... yes
>   checking for kill... yes checking for finite... yes checking for
>   sigsetjmp... no checking whether isfinite is declared... yes checking
>   whether isnan is declared... yes checking whether isinf is declared...
>   yes checking for usable _FPU_SETCW... yes checking for usable
>   fpsetprec... no checking for usable _controlfp... no checking for
>   usable _controlfp_s... no checking whether FPU control word can be
>   manipulated by inline assembler... yes checking whether double cast to
>   long preserves least significant bits... no checking for dlfcn.h...
>   (cached) yes checking whether dlsym() requires a leading underscore in
>   symbol names... no checking whether to enable thread-safety... no
>   checking whether to enable inline optimization for GCC... yes checking
>   whether to enable Zend debugging... no checking for inline... inline
>   checking target system is Darwin... no checking for MM alignment and
>   log values... done checking for mremap... yes checking for
>   sigaction... yes checking whether to enable zend signal handling...
>   yes
>
> Configuring TSRM
>
> Configuring libtool checking for a sed that does not truncate
>   output... /bin/sed checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld checking
>   if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes checking for /usr/bin/ld
>   option to reload object files... -r checking for BSD-compatible nm...
>   /usr/bin/nm -B checking how to recognize dependent libraries...
>   pass_all checking the maximum length of command line arguments...
>   1572864 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc
>   object... ok checking for objdir... .libs checking for ar... ar
>   checking for ranlib... ranlib checking for strip... strip checking if
>   cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no checking for cc option to
>   produce PIC... -fPIC checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
>   checking if cc static flag -static works... yes checking if cc
>   supports -c -o file.o... yes checking whether the cc linker
>   (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes checking
>   whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no checking dynamic
>   linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so checking how to hardcode
>   library paths into programs... immediate checking whether stripping
>   libraries is possible... yes checking if libtool supports shared
>   libraries... yes checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build static libraries... yes
>
> creating libtool appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
>
> Generating files configure: patching main/php_config.h.in configure:
>   creating ./config.status creating main/internal_functions.c creating
>   main/internal_functions_cli.c config.status: creating
>   main/build-defs.h config.status: creating scripts/phpize
>   config.status: creating scripts/man1/phpize.1 config.status: creating
>   scripts/php-config config.status: creating scripts/man1/php-config.1
>   config.status: creating sapi/cli/php.1 config.status: creating
>   sapi/phpdbg/phpdbg.1 config.status: creating sapi/cgi/php-cgi.1
>   config.status: creating ext/phar/phar.1 config.status: creating
>   ext/phar/phar.phar.1 config.status: creating main/php_config.h
>   config.status: main/php_config.h is unchanged config.status: executing
>   default commands
>
> +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ | License:                                                           |
>   | This software is subject to the PHP License, available in this     |
>   | distribution in the file LICENSE. By continuing this installation  |
>   | process, you are bound by the terms of this license agreement.     |
>   | If you do not agree with the terms of this license, you must abort |
>   | the installation process at this point.                            |
>   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> Thank you for using PHP.
>
> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-webp-dir,
>   --with-litespeed

I have tried to download https://www.litespeedtech.com/packages/lsapi/php-litespeed-7.6.tgz from litespeed and extracted it to php-7.4.1/sapi/
but still i am getting this error. I want to support webp for my server. 
Any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be comment , but I don't have 50 rep , so I wrote it here..

PHP 7.4 changed it to from `--with-litespeed` to  `--enable-litespeed`